# How can I dynamically display on or off a floating textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have such a blog site:

[image]

Basically, what I want is

> If user clicks search, then a floating semi-transparent textarea window will be displayed in the rectangle area (shown in the picture, that red orange rectangle). If user click search again, the textarea is off.

How can I do it?

What I have got so far are:

**in my page**

```
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="search">
<label for="radio3">Search</label>
```

**in my script**

```
if($(this).attr("id") == "radio3"){

}
```

I know I have to fill something in above empty bracket, to turn on the textarea or off.

I am a html5 beginner. How can I do that?

Comment: if($(this).attr("id") == "radio3"){
    $("#youtTextAreaId").toggle()
}

Comment: @IdanMagled should I create the textarea in my page and then hide it or toggle it first?

Comment: create it in the page (hidden) and the toggle function will hide and show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming from the code you've supplied you're using jQuery then you can toggle your text panels state with the following:

```js
$("#radio3").on("click",function(){
  $("#textbox").toggle();
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
.textbox {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 75px;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="search">
  <label for="radio3">Search</label>

  <div id="textbox" class="textbox">
    Use search to toggle this area. 
  </div>
</div>
```

More information on toggle - http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

CSS3 can be used to add transparency to the text area, its straight forward and widely supported, more information can be seen here - http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/opacity/.

The textbox can be positioned using CSS as well by stating position absolute and then giving it top and left values to offset it from it's parent container.

Comment: should I create the textarea in my page and then hide it or toggle it first?

Comment: You can create your text area within your HTML, using a class / id so you can target it in your JavaScript. You can use CSS to hide the container until you click search. I will extend the example to demonstrate.